# TypeScript doesn't complain when array type is extended and standard array is supplied

Tags: arrays, typescript

In TypeScript, I'm trying to extend `Array` for a special case in my app.

Here's my code: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM4FFzQN4CgoFQDSiA7olALxQBEJ5NANPoQArACGc1N7XTLAgBE4HAOYB7EPCTIqtEeKkyUAgL65cAYwA2HVKlgIUAQTiiAnlGAAPZKAAmhs5YA8KtJkhQAPlFTIcIggYgB8UHiEUFpSAQhayBJwABQAZsbIAFxGshhYjFAAdMVwwAHZccFiANoAugCUEYJR0bESOsCFOhJiyQAGMSBxYAlJ2QAk2Omyan31ANzNUahgAA7AKdMoBcWFpQELzRoa2rFyq3ASWmWoHvJpGdkeLhwWjZThkYSDqO2d3b0AOQAFQAFohDBCoMhQcAoFtkICCgjDicfnIIBxgvd3p9mhcrjcPMlqoCQBJkCYPICGos1EA))

```
enum FruitsEnum {
    Kiwi = "Kiwi",
    Pear= "Pear",
    DragonFruit = "DragonFruit",
}

class FruitArray extends Array<FruitsEnum | string> {
    constructor(fruit: FruitsEnum, ...rest: string[]) {
        console.log(`constructor: ${fruit}`);
        super(fruit, ...rest);
    }
}

const processFruit = (fruit: FruitArray) => {
    console.log('This is the fruit', fruit);
}

const main = () => {
    processFruit(['notAFruit']);
}
```

What I don't understand is why TypeScript allows `processFruit(['notAFruit'])`.  I specified that `processFruit()` takes a `FruitArray`, and yet I can give it a standard array and it accepts that.  Why?

Comment: You specify `FruitArray extends Array<FruitsEnum | string>` so the elements of the array can be of type `FruitsEnum` or `string`. If you don't want to allow plain `string`, remove it.

Comment: Well, you are using a union type so the array you are providing can contain either a value from the enum or a string and you are here using a string which is completely valid, Try passing in a number or any other type in the array and see what happens.

Comment: I would take wild guess looking at your implementation and would say what you are actually trying to achieve is this type definition.
type FruitArray = [FruitsEnum, ...rest: string[]]

Comment: TS has a structural type system and your class has not added any additional structure (e.g., a new property or method), so `string[] extends FruitArray` as well as vice versa.  If you want to  change that then add some structure to your class.  Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: This, and also, there is no point at using enum with TypeScript. Just use a type alias like `type Fruit = "Kiwi" | "Pear" | "DragonFruit"`.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu What I was trying to do is to extend the `Array` class to get the equivalent of that type definition through an actual class so that I can enforce the constraint (FruitsEnum as first argument) during runtime.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that is what I didn't realize.  I thought that simply creating a new class was sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible by extending the array class. But I think you can achieve a similar behavior if you create a class containing a property with the type I mentioned which then gets initialized through the constructor.

Comment: You're not asking this question but I would agree with @BerkKurkcuoglu that you might want to try just using the tuple type `type FruitArray = [FruitsEnum, ...string[]]` instead of having a custom class.  That may or may not be sufficient for your use case.  But this is really out of scope here so I won't digress further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  If two types are structurally identical, TypeScript treats them as the same type.  If you [extend](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) an interface or a class without adding any new members, the new interface or new class  instance type will be seen as the *same type as the parent*.  This can lead to surprising behavior, [as documented in the TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes).

In your example it means that `FruitArray` is seen as the same type as `Array<FruitsEnum | string>`, which, by the way, is also the same type as `Array<string>` because `FruitsEnum` is a subtype of `string`.  Therefore anywhere a `FruitArray` is needed, a `string[]` will suffice.

If you'd like to prevent this, the easiest way is to add some member to `FruitArray` to distinguish it structurally from `string[]`.  For example:

```
class FruitArray extends Array<FruitsEnum | string> {
    prop = ""; // anything to structurally distinguish from Array
    constructor(fruit: FruitsEnum, ...rest: string[]) {
        console.log(`constructor: ${fruit}`);
        super(fruit, ...rest);
    }
}

const main = () => {
    processFruit(['notAFruit']); // error!
    // --------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FruitArray'.
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM4FFzQN4CgoFQDSiA7olALxQBEJ5NANPoQArACGc1N7XTLAgBE4HAOYB7EPCTIqtEeKkyUAgL65cAYwA2HVKlgIUAQTiiAnlGAAPZKAAmhs5YA8KtJkhQAPlFTIcIggYgB8UHiEUAAOcBLR8jQ0ANxQAPRpUBwgFsgAFsFiUMgS-oFgWshgojo6Vg6IAYVIqHlQAGZx0C4cFoJQWlIBCJUScAAUnbIAXEayGFiMUAB0q3DAAbPDhQDaALoAlBH9UYMgqBI6wMs6EmLjAAZnwxUlcLMAJNhTKGoPB8kToRUGBosAJj9kEtVst1gEAf0NBptEM5LEJFoNqgPPJJsZkLMPD0LEdKOFIoRnpdrrd7gByAAqBUMjWKeWAHXxdKWkIRyOecggHGCuNJ5P66MxBg84x2dJAEmQJg8dMOqQy1nMYwAhP0NQBaQ1Gw3hAB+5otlotesyZjEkFAcgk7WKFjBUDp2xC+zpUFZCrk+lQiDEIA4ACMrsVStEuBwIMB7HAoM7Xe66UTzL06ctcMigA)